# Execute a function on the closing of a popup with onclosingpop

Tags: acumatica

I have a button opening the journalentry graph, then upon closing it I want to start another function on my origin screen.

So here's what I tried :

```
        public PXAction<AccountByPeriodFilter> Process;
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = LE.ActionsMessages.Process, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Update)]
        [PXButton(CommitChanges = true, OnClosingPopup = PXSpecialButtonType.Approve)]
        public virtual void process()
        {
            dostuff(); // opens the journalentry popup
        }

        public PXAction<AccountByPeriodFilter> Process2;
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = LE.ActionsMessages.Process2, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Update)]
        [PXButton(CommitChanges = true, SpecialType = PXSpecialButtonType.Approve)]
        public virtual void process2()
        {
            dostuff2(); 
        }
```

From what I understood, on closing the popup, the framework is supposed to call the first button of type "Approve" it finds. But in my case it just does nothing.

What did I miss ?

When I use "OnClosingPopup = PXSpecialButtonType.Refresh" it works fine (but I dont want to just refresh my screen, maybe I should just override the refresh button on this screen ?)

Regards,

Comment: I see it otherwise. Only 'Refresh', 'Cancel', 'Save' and 'SaveNotClose' are actually supported types and doesn't actually call the button but rather creates Callback commands similar to AutoCallback.

Comment: public PXSpecialButtonType OnClosingPopup
Gets or sets the special type of the button that will be triggerred on closing of an application
webpage that is opened in popup mode.  https://adn.acumatica.com/content/uploads/2017/08/AcumaticaFramework_DevelopmentGuide6.pdf p660. This is were I got this piece of information. so you mean that even If I override the refresh logic I can't execute my code ?

Comment: I see that 'Refresh' type issues 'RepaintControls' command, I wouldn't say that is the same as calling Refresh action.

Comment: You can check if you can execute code in the GraphExtension context by overriding the Initialize method or by defining a constructor in the Graph context. Graph constructor is the entry point of every Graph callback and will call Initialize of all of it's Graph extensions. If it doesn't reach Initialize it's no use to investigate Refresh.

Comment: I'll try this out and post the outcome, thanks !

Comment: If there's anyway to make your logic stateless it will help tremendously as they're no 100% reliable way to detect user navigation callbacks. A way to do so is to have the child popup window modify some db persisted data (think set a flag) and on every load of the parent window check for presence of that flag.

Comment: The parent is a filter dac so there's nothing to check in the db sadly

Comment: I don't know what's your use case but usually I have the child window modify the DAC of the parent window. Then when the parent window document is invalidated it can check itself to see if the child window changed something. There's no limitation on which DAC a screen can operate.

Comment: fyi i put a breakpoint on Initialize() and it is executed on the refresh callback :) I'll answer my post with an answer if I manage to do what I wanted while overriding the refresh function).